# Swiftのany someを用いた型消去の認識について

Tags: swift

以下が型消去という認識であっているでしょうか？

```swift
protocol Animal { }
struct Cat: Animal { }

let animals: [Cat] = [Cat(), Cat(), Cat()]
// ↓型消去
let animals: [some Animal] = [Cat(), Cat(), Cat()]


func getAnimal() -> Cat {
  return Cat()
}
// ↓型消去
func getAnimal() -> some Animal {
  return Cat()
}

func getAnimal() -> any Animal {
  return Bool.random() ? Cat() : Dog()
}
```